# Remove anything that is not a letter or number

Tags: java

Is there any way to remove all but letter or number in Java?

For example,

```
123$32 -> 12332
1234 abcd /n -> 1234abcd
```

Comment: There is, you could use regex for example to capture only letters and numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java has a [full regex implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) that can solve your problem with just a single line of code:

```
final String test = "123absäöü#+a";
final String result = test.replaceAll("[^\\p{IsDigit}\\p{IsAlphabetic}]", "");
System.out.println(result);
```

The `[^\\p{IsDigit}\\p{IsAlphabetic}]` means:

- `[]` any char (based on the definition within this brackets)
- `^` that is not
- `\\p{IsDigit}` a digit
- `\\p{IsAlphabetic}` a character from the alphabet

Please note that the `\\w` or [a-z] only works with US-ASCII, and is not language compatible. If you try those with the example above, some letters will be missing.

Comment: Thanks again... that was well hidden. ;)

Comment: +1 for Unicode Support ,its a new for me

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions in any programming language including Java can do just that. Check [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) article to learn how to use regular expressions in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, its easy and simple

```
        String output = "";
        String word = "AbD#$989_=+1";
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char c = word.charAt(i);
            if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {
                output += c;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("outpt: " + output);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should look into the .replaceAll method.

First of all you should make your String str for instance:

```
    String str = new String("1234$no");
    str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
    return str;
```

Basically this will replace everything NOT in the given sequences with ""

Best of luck